# How to compare values of 2 columns from different tables

Tags: php, sql, database

I have Table A with a column city

[image: city]

and Table B with 2 columns id,name

[image: id,name]

Now how can i compare the value of Table A to the 'id' of Table B and print output as 'name' column instead of 'city' column.

Basically instead of printing like this

[image: this]

i want it to print with names of cities.

my code for fetching this is

```
$result = $odb -> query("SELECT `cities` FROM `tableA`");
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple `join`:

```
select b.name city
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on b.id = a.city
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JOIN as below:
$result = $odb -> query("SELECT B.Name as cities FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id");